# how to Receive data/ack from RAK831 gateway to lora node?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, lora, lorawan

I'm new to the forums so apologies if this has been answered before but I've done a search and can't find anything on this topic...

**I'm not able to Receive data/ack from RAK831 gateway to lora end-node**

note: I'm able to receive data/packets from lora end-node to Gateway

my configuration is

A RAK831 433MHz version

I follow the instruction of https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/labs/story/rak831-lora-gateway-from-package-to-online to make raspberry-pi3 based lora gateway

I just modify the global_config.json file according to Rak support recommendation and with my 433 frequency plan, config file given in below link.

http://support.rakwireless.com/uploads/files/1516933601249-global_config_eu433.json

For the end-node I’m using a custom board with RFM98W 433mhz LoRa and Arduino Mini Pro.
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-Lora-Radio-Node-V1-0-SX1278-Rola-433Mhz-Radio-Module-ATmega328P-RFM98-Wireless-DIY-Kit/32859077350.html

For this testing I use basic tests programs comes with lora gateway library
util_pkt_logger program for  record all the packets received in a log file and 
util_tx_test program to send test packets with a LoRa concentrator

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: @SoumyaKanti thank you, I visit the links given by you